# Cache problem with DropDownList and VaryByControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, outputcache

I have a page with a single dropdown. Depending on what the user chooses in this dropdown, a pretty huge report is generated. The cache directive for the page reads:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="14400" VaryByParam="none" VaryByControl="lstUsers" %>
```

The drop-down is defined as:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstUsers" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            onselectedindexchanged="lstUsers_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

And the code-behind:

```
if (lstPartners.SelectedValue != "")
{
PanelChoose.Visible = false;
PanelInfo.Visible = true;

GetReport();
}
```

Now when I first choose an User, the report generates fine. If I go back and choose another, the first User's report is shown again...

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using the .NET Framework 3.5 with Service Pack 1.

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using master/content pages?

OutputCache VaryByControl won't work properly for content pages.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=465461